# AWS: create json template to create auto scaling group to create 2 EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I am trying to create a CloudFormation template to create an Auto Scaling group, so that I can spin up 2 instances out of it.

I have created the Auto Scaling group, but I do not know how to write the template for creating 2 EC2 instances from the Auto Scaling group.

Here is my CloudFormation template:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Resources": {
        "ASASGHWD2": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
            "Properties": {}
        },
        "EC2I24ZL9": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {}
        },
        "EC2I22IAP": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I just need a maximum of two instances. One should always be running, if the CPU utilization is more than 90 % on the first one, then the second instance should come up.

I have not edited the properties. Just any simple default configuration will work for me.

Comment: Please Edit your question and include a copy of the template you have created so far. Setting `DesiredCapacity` should launch two instances, but any scaling policies may change this quantity.

Comment: hi John, i have copied the template in question.

Comment: Before providing a full answer, I must ask... Why are you using a CloudFormation template for this task instead of just doing it through the EC2 management console? (There are some good reasons for doing so, but it is more complex. Have you used Auto Scaling via the console before?)

Comment: Sir, the client requirement is like this. they want some chef code to be used in this template later to bootstrap the machines.

Comment: Hi John, i was asked to initially create a json template with autoscale group, 2 instances, so that we can replicate our this infrastructure again and again.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that all you have done is drag an Auto Scaling icon onto a template using the AWS CloudFormation Designer. As a result, there is **no configuration** included in the definition.

You template would need to define:

- A **Launch Configuration** that defines the new configuration for Amazon EC2 instances that are launched by Auto Scaling (eg Instance Type, AMI, Security Group)
- An **Auto Scaling group** that defines how many instances to launch, in which network to launch and whether to link to a Load Balancer
- **CloudWatch Alarms** that define metrics to monitor to determine when to scale
- **Auto Scaling policies** that define how many instances to add/remove when the CloudWatch Alarms are triggered

For example of these configuration, see: [Auto Scaling Template Snippets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-autoscaling.html)

If you are unfamiliar with any of the above resources, I recommend that you create an Auto Scaling group using the EC2 management console and familiarize yourself with the features, functions and settings associated with Auto Scaling. You will then be able to translate these into a CloudFormation template for future re-use.

**Bottom line:** Try to understand Auto Scaling before you automate it.

Comment: Before trying to understand the snippets, read the documentation on Auto Scaling and play with it in the console. Only after that should you attempt to understand the CloudFormation snippets.